# How to run the oracle services in the server?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

Actually I have the jdbc url address `jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.1:1521:CUSTDB` 
and the database I am going to connect is located in server.
My computer is not connecting to the database as oracle server is not ON in server as I dont know how to run the oracle in server in windows.
Can someone tell me how to run the oracle services in server?

Comment: So far what have you tried?

Comment: i have opened my server and there i only found toad for oracle and dont know what to do then after

Comment: "Services, server, server is not on in server, ..." >>> **What?** are you talking about? I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. TOAD is a tool you use to connect to a database. Apparently, you don't have it (a database) installed on your computer. Where is it, then? Is it accessible to you over the network? Or do you want to install your own copy of an Oracle database? If so, no problem - go to OTN, download & install 11g Express Edition (requires a few NEXT clicks). Otherwise, please, explain what you want.

Comment: What you want? java code to connect to your database ?

Comment: First you learn to search things in google. Then try something. If you have a problem please come with something that you have tried. This is not the place to teach you things. Follow some tutorials, and go through the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/gettingstart.htm#NETAG006

Comment: ok thanks i will see it